# Xul listbox without the scrollbar, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, css, xul

When a Xul's listbox have more itens than it can show, [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/List_Controls) says *"A scroll bar will appear that the user can use to display the additional rows"*.

Is there a way of disable the scroll bar so that it will never appear?

Comment: Can you apply `overflow: hidden` to it? Or some other CSS property, perhaps?

Comment: @Chris Morgan yes, I can use css, but this one didn't worked.. nothing changed here..

Comment: OK, I haven't done much with XUL so that was my only idea.

Comment: @Chris Morgan ok, thanks anyway.. maybe this with some other answer (or some discovery of mine) will produce the right answer.. :)

Comment: I face the same issue, today :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a hack and is not guaranteed to work in future versions, but you could put this in your stylesheet:

```
#yourlistbox-id listboxbody {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

<listboxbody> is an [anonymous element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Anonymous_Content) hosting the <listitem> elements of the listbox (you can see it with the [DOM inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6622/)), and it's this element, not the listbox itself has the scrollbars via the overflow property (also can be observed in the DOMi).

Comment: Thanks, it's working! You say it's a hack becouse it's not documented? Many things that I need to use from Xul are not documented.. anyway.. I may award the bounty in 18 hours.

Comment: @Tom Brito: I say it's a hack because listboxbody is an implementation detail which is subject to change. It's the best you can use, unfortunately.

Comment: @Nickolay by the way, how did you found it? Searching directly in the Xulrunner source code?

Comment: @Tom Brito: As I said, using the DOM Inspector. The scrollbars are usually controlled by the overflow CSS property, so I was looking for an element inside the listbox with "overflow" set to "auto" (on the "Computed Style" / "CSS Rules" panes). I should probably mention that to see the listboxbody you have to set 'View -> Show Anonymous Content'. Let me know if you have additional questions about this.

Comment: @Nickolay the MDN looks not much organized.. How was I supposed to find https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM_Inspector before I know that it exists?

Comment: @Tom Brito: not sure why you chose to direct that comment to me. MDC is a wiki, so you can edit it too.

Comment: @Nickolay I'm just used to always direct the comment.. nothing particular.. :) By the way, I use to edit that wiki, but those who work there should at least have a page that lists all existing pages. This I can't do for them, as I don't have access to a list of all pages. I'll e-mail this request to them.

Comment: I sent a bug report about this, and it was accepted: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=623869

Comment: @Nickolay Maybe you could help me with the DOM Inspector: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648365/how-to-inspect-my-standalone-xul-app-using-dom-inspector-or-similar